# Disable the Xcode utilities panel auto-display feature

Tags: xcode, mouseover

How do I disable the Xcode auto-display feature of the utilities panel (aka the far right pane that holds the identity inspector etc)?

In full screen mode (coding, not just in the storyboard) whenever my mouse curser gets moved all the way to the right of the screen, the utilities panel displays automatically. It is distracting and unwanted. If I need that panel I can click the button in the upper right to display it, or use a keyboard shortcut. It doesn't seem like anything else is autodisplaying, just the right side panel. Once I move the mouse away from it, the panel disappears again. Maddening I tell you.

Comment: default one is command+option+0, it is supposed to show if you click this shortcut

Comment: btw, which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: @zeytin Thanks for the response! I'm using Xcode 12.3. Exactly, the panel that is toggled with command+option+0. The keyboard shortcut does work for me but sadly, using it still doesn't stop the pane from auto-displaying.

Comment: This happens in Xcode 13.3 and is just ridiculous. As soon as I grab the scrollbar both it and the content I'm trying to scroll is obscured behind a panel that I thought I'd hidden...