# How to enable automatically showing and hiding the inspector panel in Xcode when moving the cursor to the right side of the screen?

Tags: xcode, inspector, xcode14

How can I enable the feature the allows the user to move their cursor to the right side of the screen to open the Inspector panel in Xcode 14.3? It seems like a nice feature but I have only seen other people do it.

I have looked all over the settings panel for a setting for this, but I can't find it. I have also searched for it but I found nothing.

How could I enable this?

Comment: I don’t think this is possible. Are you sure you have seen people do it, or were they using the keyboard shortcut to toggle the inspector: command-option-0

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure that I have seen multiple YouTube videos where this has been done but right now I can't find them. And this I think is the same just that I want to turn it on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373616/disable-the-xcode-utilities-panel-auto-display-feature

Comment: Sounds like it might only happen when Xcode is in full screen mode. I don’t use that so never saw this behaviour.

Comment: Yeah but I don't have it in full screen mode.

Comment: Never mind, I just didn't hold it there for long enough.